# Class added to ClassList is not being applied

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a page that when a button is pressed, the colors of the button and the background swap.

```
document.querySelector("body.light").classList.toggle("dark");
document.querySelector("button.dark").classList.toggle("light");
```

But even though the "dark" class is toggled on, it is not applied to the background. I've noticed that when I swap the CSS classes (put the .light class first instead of the .dark class), the reverse happens, where the background color changes, but not the button color. Is there an issue with the CSS?

Here is the full code, with a bunch of console.log's to show that the classes are definitely added:

```js
var darklightArray;

function darklight() {
  darklightArray = document.querySelector("body.light").classList;

  console.log("Before");
  console.log("body: ", document.querySelector("body.light").classList);
  console.log("button: ", document.querySelector("button.dark").classList);

  document.querySelector("body.light").classList.toggle("dark"); //Changes the class to dark, then toggled again turns it light
  document.querySelector("button.dark").classList.toggle("light"); //Toggles the color of the button
  //document.querySelector("button.dark").classList.remove("dark");

  console.log("After");
  console.log("body: ", document.querySelector("body.light").classList);
  console.log("button: ", document.querySelector("button.dark").classList);
  if (darklightArray.length == 2) {
    document.querySelector("button.dark").innerHTML = "To light mode";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button.dark").innerHTML = "To dark mode";
  }
}
```

```css
.dark {
  background-color: #07000c;
  color: #D8D8D8;
}

.light {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Darklight Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/darklight_testing.css">
  <script src="darklight_testing.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="light">
  <div class="darklight">
    <button type="button" onclick="darklight()" class="dark">To dark mode</button>
  </div>
  Content
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *toggle* both *light* and *dark* for both `body` and `button`

Comment: `classList` is not an array, it is a __live__ DOMTokenList, containing space-separated class name sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

You can use `toggle` or `replace` methods to achieve this.

[MDN Docs for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

1. If `toggle` is used, each element must be toggled twice to add a class and to remove a class.
2. If `replace` is used, then a single call is enough.

`replace` is not supported in IE, Safari.

3. Don't use class to select the elements. Since you have changed the classes in first click, the elements cannot be selected again. Consider using `id` or `data-` attributes.

```js
var darklightArray;

function darklight()
{
  var bodyelem = document.body;
  var buttonelem = document.getElementById("toggleButton");

  bodyelem.classList.toggle("dark");
  bodyelem.classList.toggle("light");
  buttonelem.classList.toggle("light");
  buttonelem.classList.toggle("dark");
}
```

```css
.dark {
  background-color: #07000c;
  color: #D8D8D8;
}

.light {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Darklight Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/darklight_testing.css">
  <script src="darklight_testing.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="light">
  <div class="darklight">
    <button type="button" id="toggleButton" onclick="darklight()" class="dark">To dark mode</button>
  </div>
  Content
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I gave the button an id of `darklight_button` so I could use `document.querySelector("#darklight_button")`. And since there's just one body, I just used `document.body` to toggle both classes, so there's only one at a time. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are appending class `dark` and `light`, but not replacing it with one another, few minor updates to your `js` and `css` and it works fine, hope it helps :)

```js
var darklightArray;

function darklight() {
  darklightArray = document.querySelector("button").classList;
  document.querySelector("body").classList.toggle("dark");
  document.querySelector("button").classList.toggle("dark");
  if (darklightArray.length == 2) {
    document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = "To light mode";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("button").innerHTML = "To dark mode";
  }
}
```

```css
body, button {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  color: #000000;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #07000c;
  color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="darklight">
  <button type="button" onclick="darklight()" class="btn">To dark mode</button>
</div>
Content
```